# How to pass variable inside js?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a variable inside a method of js so that I can get some value as return, example

```
  getId: function (pos) {
    var myVar = $('.myDiv li:nth-child(pos) .myInnerDiv .myInnerMostDiv').attr('id');
    return myVar;
  }
```

And then call this as

```
this.getId(6); //where 6 is the pos
```

However this seems to be not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$('.myDiv li:nth-child(' + pos +') .myInnerDiv .myInnerMostDiv').attr('id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are writing `pos` directly in the string, so it is taken as is... What you want is concatenate its value instead!

```
getId: function (pos) {
    var myVar = $('.myDiv li:nth-child('+pos+') .myInnerDiv .myInnerMostDiv').attr('id');
    return myVar;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this:

```
var myVar = $('.myDiv li:nth-child(pos) .myInnerDiv .myInnerMostDiv').attr('id');
```

To:

```
var myVar = $(`.myDiv li:nth-child(${pos}) .myInnerDiv .myInnerMostDiv`).attr('id');
```

It concatenates pos into the string by using ES6's template litteral

Comment: what you use here is called string interpolation and its part of ECMAscript6 and may not work on every browsers right now. surely you can use BABEL to trans-pile it to the plain js. you can see the browser support at http://www.caniuse.com/#search=literals